# How do I modify a linked list node using a void?

Tags: c, nodes

I have a program, which has a node called head. I want to set head to NULL, however I want to do it inside a void. So I pass the head node to the method:

```
void removeNode(node* head) {
head = NULL;
}
```

However this does not change head in the main function, only in the void. Does anyone know how to change the value of a node that is passed as a parameter to a void?

P.S: As a requirement, I cannot use the free function, or any memory unallocation method.

Comment: `void removeNode(node ** head) { *head =NULL; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to do this instead:

```
void removeNode(node** head) {
    (*head) = NULL;
}
```

This changes the actual pointer to `NULL`, so that it no longer points to anything.

Comment: How do I loop through the list and set the last node to NULL?

Comment: @LeeWhite and as an added info, instead of passing head from your calling function, pass the address of head.